# Graphs of convex polytopes

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, convex-geometry, planar-graphs, polytopes

Some constraints for the graphs of convex polytopes are well known:

- In 3 dimensions, the graph must be planar and 3-connected (actually a complete characterization, which likely cannot be extended to higher dimensions).
- In $k$ dimensions, it must be $k$-connected.

What are other constraints?

I feel that there should be many more such constraints, but I cannot find any reference, so any hint or pointer would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such constraints define the *realizability* of a graph as a $d$-dimensional polytope. Some such constraints can be found in Grünbaum, *Convex Polytopes*, 2003, Chapter 11.